# tkinter integration with glib mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter, glib

Is it possible to integrate `tkinter` with glib `mainloop` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
app=TkinterApp()

def refreshApp():
    app.update()
    return True

gobject.idle_add(refreshApp)
loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Comment: Do you mean [`tkinter.Tk`](https://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html#tkinter.Tk) by `TkinterApp` ?