# Can't get EOS event when video ends playing

Tags: python, tkinter, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm working on a small application in python / tkinter, in which I'm playing videos.
I'd need to be able to detect when the end of the video has been reached, to take some actions, but I can't find a way to do that.

I tried to get EOS notifications, but my message handler never gets called.

Here is a code snippet showing the issue:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import os

import tkinter

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject  # noqa E402

gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GstVideo  # noqa E402,F401


def stop_video(gst):
    gst.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    gst.set_state(Gst.State.READY)


def set_frame_handle(bus, message, frame_id):
    structure = message.get_structure()
    if structure is not None:
        if structure.get_name() == 'prepare-window-handle':
            display_frame = message.src
            display_frame.set_property('force-aspect-ratio', True)
            display_frame.set_window_handle(frame_id)


def quit_window(player, window):
    stop_video(player)
    window.destroy()


def on_message(bus, message):
    # TODO doesn't work
    print("on message")
    t = message.type
    if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("eos")


Gst.init(None)

window = tkinter.Tk()
player = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', None)
fullname = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
window.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: quit_window(player, window))

window.title("Example tk-gstreamer video player")
window.geometry('640x360')

display_frame = tkinter.Frame(window, bg='')
display_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, anchor=tkinter.NW, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
frame_id = display_frame.winfo_id()

player.set_property('uri', 'file://%s' % fullname)
player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

bus = player.get_bus()
bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
bus.connect('sync-message::element', set_frame_handle, frame_id)
bus.connect('message', on_message)

window.mainloop()
```

To test that, one can do (the video is small, which is handy here :) ):

```bash
wget https://github.com/ncarrier/joyeuse/raw/master/examples/copie/Secrets/Tutos%20vid%C3%A9o/4-Pause-play.mp4
python3 ./snippets/video/gstreamer2.py 4-Pause-play.mp4
```

But I never obtain the "on message" log (not talking about the "eos" one...).

**Extra question**: Is there a good resource for learning how to use gstreamer in python? C tutorials aren't really appropriate and the python gstreamer API I found isn't adapted to beginners like me :/

Comment: I've a funny feeling that you should be using `bus.connect('message::eos', on_message)` to get that working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have the answer, the idea is to use gtk's main loop instead of tk's.

Here's the SO Q/A I used to do that: [tkinter integration with glib mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884528/tkinter-integration-with-glib-mainloop)

I'll post an updated snippet as soon as I have something fully working (there are a few remaining issues still though).